# Xcode Interface Builder XIB Compiler Error

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xib, nib

I am currently learning to use Xcode. 
When I tried to run the Xcode project by clicking on the run button , I keep getting this message :

> "Xcode: Interface Builder XIB Compiler Error" and "Build Failed".

Any ideas how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: What is the Xcode Version? What kind of project: OS X iOS? Language: Swift? Objective-C? What kind of Template you have chosen?

Comment: Xcode : Version 6.4.                                                                                  Project : OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2 (14C2055)                                                                                       Language : Swift Programming Language.                                        Template : Single View Application

Comment: Have you tried a clean Build? Xcode -> Product -> Clean

Comment: Try to setup up new empty project and look if it fails again. In my case I was trying to get this error message by deleting storyboard and LaunchScreen.xib, but the app compiles without errors :/

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggested methods but the build still failed. I did Xcode -> Product  -> Clean and it failed. I tried to set up a new empty project , and ran the application but the build still failed. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Wow! Ok it's very strange! Go to Xcode Preferences -> Location and look if  under Command Line Tools Xcode is displayed there. Last idea is to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Hi Miralem Cebic, I reinstalled Xcode as you suggested and ran the application --- this time it worked and the IOS Simulator appeared. I am going to read through the tutorials and create my first app project. Thanks a lot !